# Position dialog in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, dialog

I am working on application which works in an iframe. The iframe is pretty long, but has never a scrollbar - but the outer page obviously does.

In the iframe I am showing modal dialog (the one from dojo) and it is required that the dialog should be positioned as 10px from the top of the viewport. But it seems that jquery does not have any usable function which will determine the correct position with respect to the current toolbar settings as (scrollTop requires to be called using element from the outer page and there is none as the iframe is longer than the viewport). Also it is not possible to use css position fixed, as it needs to be in the top level document.

I have also tried to use the dojo support object window, but the positioning also does not work correctly...

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could add a handler to the parent page "onscroll" event. On the handler you can retrieve the top position of the scroll and send this value to the child frame through a function, like this:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
        var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
        var top = (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0);
        document.getElementById("IFRAME_ID").contentWindow.SetTopValue(top);
    };
```

On the child side, set the modal div to a fixed css position, and on the javascript function that receive the parent scroll value you set the "top" property as "scrollvalue + 10". Something like this:

```
function SetTopValue(top) {
        document.getElementById("MODAL_DIV").style.top = (10 + top) + "px";
    }
```